# writing inline style with emmet when creating jsx element by writing abbreviation

Tags: css, styles, jsx, emmet

I am using vscode and learning to work with emmet and I want to apply style to the jsx element by using the abbreviation of the style at the time of creating the element. How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add following in USER SETTINGS inorder to activate emmet in JSX.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
     "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```

source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4962

I looked at the [emmet cheatsheet](https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/), there is not any abbreviation that create an element with style attribute.

And [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) suggest to use css classes instead of inline styles:

> Are inline styles bad?
>   CSS classes are generally better for performance than inline styles.

Comment: Thanks, but I just wanted to know if there is any abbr for adding style.

Comment: @MohdRizwan as I said in the answer there is no abbreviation for that.

Comment: this question is not about if its suggested by reactjs, I just want to know how can we do that, saying that I couldn't find anything related to this question is not an answer. Moreover I didn't ask how can we enable emmet with jsx. So nothing is related to question in your answer.

Comment: @MohdRizwan there is no abbreviation in emmet to create inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Updating in 2021, just in case anyone comes here searching for answers.

If you have `"javascript": "javascriptreact"` set in your config, you can add a style prop in Emmet by using `\` to indicate a literal character the same way you would in a regular expression. Closing curly braces inside the block need a `\` in front of them.

For example:

```
div[style={{ padding: '0px'\}}]
```

Translates to:

```
<div style={{ padding: '0px'}}></div>
```

Here's a more complex Emmet expression with some object nesting (using the mui sx prop):

```
div[sx={{ p: { sm: 2, lg: 4\}, m: { sm: 2, lg: 4\}\}}]>div[sx={{ p: 4\}}]+div
```

Translates to:

```
  <div sx={{ p: { sm: 2, lg: 4}, m: { sm: 2, lg: 4}}}>
    <div sx={{ p: 4}}></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

I only tested in vscode, but this will probably work in other text editors too. I also couldn't find any mention of `\` in the Emmet docs, but it is working reliably for me.